# Get httpServletRequest in java sending a http get through react

Tags: reactjs, servlets, get, httprequest, axios

I need to send multiple variables through a htttp get request using axios in react, problem is, I can't send them on the get header as there is too many information.

I have experience using using jquery datatables plugin with ajax, where I can send data like this:

```
inventoriesTable = $('#dt-inventories-table').DataTable({
            ajax:{
                url:"path goes here",
                type: "GET",
                data:function(d){
                    d.data1 = $("#data1").val();
                    d.data2 = $("#data2").val();
                    d.data3 = $("#data3").val();
                    d.data4 = $("#data4").val();
                    d.data5 = $("#data5").val();
                },
                dataSrc:function(json){             
                },
                error:function(){
                }
            },              
            columns: [
                        { "data": "col1" },
                        { "data": "col2" }
                       ],               
        });

    });`
```

And then I can get it in java with an HttpServletRequest doing something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="path goes here",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public void someFunction(HttpServletRequest request){
        String data1 = request.getParameter("data1");
        String data2 = request.getParameter("data2");
        String data3 = request.getParameter("data3");
    }
```

**Is there a way I can do this using axios in react?**